How to fix DataDriver error in Robot Framework: "ImportError: cannot import name : "FileNotFoundError" from 'pandas.compat"?
I get this error when hovering on the DataDriver Library
Unresolved library: DataDriver. Error generating libspec: Importing library 'DataDriver' failed: ImportError: cannot import name : "FileNotFoundError" from 'pandas.compat' (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py) Consider adding the needed paths to the "robot.pythonpath" setting and calling the "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" action.robotframework

This is what I have in my code.

Hoping I could get answers here again. This is my first time asking here again since graduating from college last 3 years ago. Thanks!

Your IDE is trying to generate documentation from the DataDriver library, but this special library does not have keywords and documentation.
You should ignore the error and run your test case to verify it is working.
